# Tableview first section bounces back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

[image: screendump][image: screendump]
[image: screendump]

In a TableView (Swift 4.0, Xcode 9) the first section is cropped (see second screen dump). When you 'pull down' you can see the text is still there, but if you let go it bounces back (see first screen dump).

I tried adding the following code:

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
           return 15
            }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
           return 18
            }
```

But that didn't help.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have another view (maybe a UITableViewCell) added on top of your table view. Try clicking on the white area here and deleting it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I guess that is just the background, not a view? I've added another screenshot.

Comment: You shouldn't need to guess. What do you see in the right-hand pane of Xcode if you click on that area? You should be able to see what class it is. Also, what happens if you delete it?

Comment: When I click there the right-hand pane says 'class UIView'... that view contains the safe area, tableview, custom cell (with ui elements) and toolbar (see screendump). If I delete it, I also delete the tableview, custom cell and toolbar.